# NEO4J error : Invalid input 's': expected 'n/N'

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-python-driver

For the below cypher query, I am getting an error

Cypher Query tried:

```
match (n:attribAct) where not tolower(n.Aliases) contains tolower(n.name) set n.Aliases = n.name+","+n.Aliases as x return x;
```

Error:

```
Invalid input 's': expected 'n/N' (line 1, column 115 (offset: 114))
"match (n:attribAct) where not tolower(n.Aliases) contains tolower(n.name) set n.Aliases = n.name+","+n.Aliases as x return x;"
```

How could I fix this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: The statement is not returning any value. Remove `..as x`

Answer (score 0):

As @BurakSerdar said, the `SET` command does not need an alias.

Your code:

```
match (n:attribAct)
where not tolower(n.Aliases) contains tolower(n.name)
set n.Aliases = n.name+","+n.Aliases as x
return x;
```

FIX:

```
match (n:attribAct) 
where not tolower(n.Aliases) contains tolower(n.name) 
set n.Aliases = n.name+","+n.Aliases 
return n;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AS` keyword can only be used in `WITH` and `RETURN` clauses.

You can return `n` this way:

```
MATCH (n:attribAct) 
WHERE NOT TOLOWER(n.Aliases) CONTAINS TOLOWER(n.name) 
SET n.Aliases = n.name + "," + n.Aliases 
RETURN n;
```

By the way, if `n.Aliases` was actually a list of strings (instead of a comma-delimited string), this would work:

```
MATCH (n:attribAct) 
WHERE NONE(a in n.Aliases WHERE TOLOWER(a) = TOLOWER(n.name)) 
SET n.Aliases = n.Aliases + n.name
RETURN n;
```